# When using the Custom HTML app, is it possible to display custom portfolio fields in a rally grid?

Tags: rally, appsdk2

My goal is to display some custom porfolio fields (the field is called executive champion) in a custon HTML app using a rally grid on the dashboard.  I have reviewed the docs and some examples and it does not look like this is possible.  Has anyone accomplished this and how? My code is as follows.  I used the following to get started https://github.com/davidpthomas/BasicRallyGrid.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>BasicRallyGrid</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc2/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function () {
                // Custom Rally App that displays Stories in a grid.
//
// Note: various console debugging messages intentionally kept in the code for learning purposes

Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',      // The parent class manages the app 'lifecycle' and calls launch() when ready
    componentCls: 'app',          // CSS styles found in app.css

    // Entry Point to App
    launch: function() {

      console.log('our first app');     // see console api: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api
      this._loadData();                 // we need to prefix with 'this.' so we call a method found at the app level.
    },

    // Get data from Rally
    _loadData: function() {

      var myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
          model: 'PortfolioItem',
          autoLoad: true,                         // <----- Don't forget to set this to true! heh
          listeners: {
              load: function(myStore, myData, success) {
                  console.log('got data!', myStore, myData);
                  this._loadGrid(myStore);      // if we did NOT pass scope:this below, this line would be incorrectly trying to call _createGrid() on the store which does not exist.
              },
              scope: this                         // This tells the wsapi data store to forward pass along the app-level context into ALL listener functions
          },
          fetch: ['Executive Champion', 'Name', 'ScheduleState']   // Look in the WSAPI docs online to see all fields available!
        });

    },

    // Create and Show a Grid of given stories
    _loadGrid: function(myStoryStore) {

      var myGrid = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
        store: myStoryStore,
        columnCfgs: [         
          'Executive Champion', 'Name', 'ScheduleState'
        ]
      });

      this.add(myGrid);       

      console.log('what is this?', this);

    }

});


            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name:"BasicRallyGrid",
                parentRepos:""
            });

        });
    </script>


    <style type="text/css">
        .app {
     /* Add app styles here */
}

    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you try to do?

Comment: I updated with the code I have used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly possible to display PI custom field values in a grid.
Even if your custom field has a space in the DisplayName, remove the space from 'Executive Champion' in your code.

Here is an example. I have a custom field on portfolio item object that is shown in the Setup>Workspaces & Projects as follows:

Name: PiCustom

DisplayName: PiCustom

Workspace admin rights are required to see that page.

[WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) references this field as `c_PiCustom` (with c_ prepended automatically to indicate a custom field)

In my code either one works fine:
 `PiCustom`, `c_PiCustom`

If a workspace admin changes this custom field's DisplayName to include a space as follows:

Name: PiCustom

DisplayName: Pi Custom

It will still be displayed as `c_PiCustom` in [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/)

and either one of those two ways to reference this field in my code will still work:
`PiCustom`,`c_PiCustom`

but `Pi Custom` will not work.

Remove the space in your code. Or check exact spelling of that field in the WS API and follow that convention.

Here is a full example using [2.0rc3](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/):

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function() {
                this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallygrid',
                    model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
                    enableRanking: true,
                    storeConfig: {
                      context: {
                          context: this.getContext().getDataContext()
                      }
                    },
                   {
                        dataIndex: 'FormattedID'
                    },{
                        dataIndex: 'Name',
                    },
                     {
                        dataIndex: 'PiCustom'
                    }
                    ]
                });
    }
});
```